# Apache: unrestrict a file in a restricted location

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, authentication

given that Apache applies `<Location>` directives AFTER `<Files>` directives, how would one apply a "require all granted" to a single file in a location?
in the below wxample, I want the rss feed to be public, while everything else is restricted...

Or will this have to be changed to a `<Directory>` instead?

Example:

```
<Location "/doku">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    AuthLDAPURL  --------
    AuthLDAPBindDN   --------
    AuthLDAPBindPassword -------
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "test"
    Require ldap-user user
</Location>
<Files "/doku/feed.php">
    Allow from all
    require all granted
</Files>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Require all granted` is 2.4 config, while `Order`/`Allow`/`Deny` is 2.2 config - which are you on?

Assuming it's 2.2, try this:

```
<Directory /path/to/doku>
    # all the existing config
    <Files feed.php>
        Satisfy any
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

Comment: "Most importantly, <Location> directives should not be used to control access to filesystem locations", a quote from http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#location

Comment: @FINESEC Well, that only matters when multiple locations point to a single filesystem location, where you want the resources controlled from a filesystem perspective.. but fair enough, edited.